# Android app runs in emulator but when run on phone, logcat shows no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

When I run my app on emulator, everything works fine, but wen run on phone, the logcat in android studio shows error: - android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: posts (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT pid, post FROM posts.

When I inspect the database using Android Device Monitor, the tables have all been created and have the rows which I have inserted in it through emulator.
I tried directly running the app from android studio on my phone as well as copying the apk file from app>build>outputs>apk folder into my phone and then running the app, both ways it shows the same error.

```
public List<String> getAllPosts() {
    pdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<String> postsList = new ArrayList<>();

    String columns[] = {pid, post};
    Cursor cursor = pdb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("Cursor in pdb", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        int postIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(post);
        String post = cursor.getString(postIndex);
        postsList.add(post);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return postsList;
}
```

Comment: To give the specified answer. can you please show the exact code that you use in SELECT pid, post FROM posts.

Comment: Have added the posts table code above, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get SQLite databse file from an Android real device if it is not rooted. 
Because to access the data folder of your application you have to provide the permission for it.

But you can run your application in an android emulator and following is the way:

From DDMS, in Devices menu select your emulator.

You can see data folder in File Explorer.

Path is: data->data->Application Package Name->Databases->Database Name

As you mention you can see in emulator.

```
for developer purpose use emulator.
```

If you want to  pull/export the database and analyse it more effectively, you can easily do this with [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

Comment: I can see the database using Db Browser and it shows all the tables have been created as well as rows in some tables where i have inserted data